# Not able to pass values from Parent to child in Angular

Tags: angular, angular12

I am trying to write a very simple program of passing value from parent to child component. In the below code, I am trying to print firstName(John) but as shown in the screenshot, it's not getting printed.

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstName = "John";
}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<app-cards>
  [firstName]="firstName"
</app-cards>
```

***card.component.ts***

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cards',
  templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cards.component.css']
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() firstName : string | undefined;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

***card.component.html***

```
<div>
    First Name: {{ firstName }}
</div>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.component.html` file is wrong.  You have `[firstName]` between the `<app-cards>` element tags instead of having it as an attribute.

#### app.component.html

```
<app-cards
  [firstName]="firstName">
</app-cards>
```